# Accessing the camera in Windows Mobile 6 with PythonCE

Tags: windows, mobile, pythonce

I have a windows mobile device - HTC Touch Viva - and PythonCE installed on it. I want to capture the camera image using python script. I have ctypes in PythonCE, so was wondering if I could load the DLL that controls the camera and access those methods directly.

Please let me know if anyone has done this before.